# Change partition type in windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Is there a way to change the partition type of a partition of an external HDD in windows to one that windows does not support? For example change an ntfs partition to ext3 or Solaris.

Are there any free programs that can do this or would hex editing the id work? I don't mean formatting, simply changing the partition table type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EASEUS Partition Manager](http://www.partition-tool.com/) to do that, however, as you already said, it is not a partition type compatible with your Windows and it will not be listed as a Windows partition, I mean, you cant use your external hard drive with your windows anymore.

Comment: should i make the disk 'raw' before using that program to partition it or that program actually can change partition types? Am downloading... it thanks for suggestion. I think i need to select 'format partition' right? It has ext2 and ext3 options only.

Comment: You will need to format your partition as ext2 or ext3, it is not possible to change it without clean your partitions.

Comment: Should i select create as: PRIMARY or LOGICAL as partition type? Thanks it works, will mark as answer.